# Backbonejs scope issue, variable becoming undefined somehow

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, scope

I have a simple music app written using backbone.js.  I'm having trouble with the code below in one of my models:

```
MyApp.Models.Program = Backbone.Model.extend({
    toPlaylist: function(options, callback) {
        console.log("Converting program to playlist");

        var self = this;
        console.log(self.get('name'));
        this.stationHasLicense(function (licensedStation) {
          console.log(self.get('name'));  // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined 
          // bunch of other logic
        });
    },
});
```

The first self.get works fine.  The second self.get in the stationHasLicense callback, however, throws the error.  I'm using var self = this all over other areas of my app to keep scope, but I'm not sure why this instance is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use bind from [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) to bind *this* context when exec the func.

```
MyApp.Models.Program = Backbone.Model.extend({
    toPlaylist: function(options, callback) {
        console.log("Converting program to playlist");

        var self = this;
        console.log(self.get('name'));
        this.stationHasLicense(_.bind(function (licensedStation) {
          console.log(this.get('name')); 
          // bunch of other logic
        }, this));
    },
});
```

Can find more discussions on the topics on that=this or self=this:

- [Understanding Bind and bindAll in Backbone.js](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2011/08/18/understanding-bind-and-bindall-in-backbone.html)
- [Is var self = this; a bad pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371333/is-var-self-this-a-bad-pattern)
- [Getting Out of Binding Situations in JavaScript](http://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations)
- [what-is-the-difference-between-this-self-window-and-window-self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218292/what-is-the-difference-between-this-self-window-and-window-self)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and links.  For whatever reason, if I use anything except for "self" in the example above, it works.  No idea why...it really makes zero sense.

Comment: You may be stepping over on 'window.self' object. Added a refer to the self, window, and window.self.