# 'this' being scoped to window object when creating JS object where function is stored in a hash

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, dependency-injection

I'm not sure if the title to this makes any sense, but essentially I am trying to write a very simple Javascript dependency injection container for an app I am working on.

This is the container:

```
jedi = new function() {
    var library = {};

    this.module = function(name, module) {
        if (arguments.length == 1) {
            return library[name];
        }

        library[name] = module;
    };
};
```

I then create a Backbone model and add it as a dependency like so:

```
(function () {

    var addColourSchemeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        getColourJSON: function(prop) {
            var cols = this.get(prop).split(',');
            return {
                R: cols[0],
                G: cols[1],
                B: cols[2]
            };
        }
    });

    jedi.module('AddColourSchemeModel', addColourSchemeModel);

})();
```

The problem occurs when I try to create a new instance of this module like so:

```
var colourModel = new jedi.module('AddColourSchemeModel')({
    // json object containing model values
});
```

I get an error `Object [object global] has no method 'set'`.

The strange thing is the Backbone Model initialize methods etc are being called, but `this` is being scoped to the window instead of the object being initialized, this is where the error is ocurring as it is trying to call `this.set` at some point but this is actually the window.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `jedi.module('AddColourSchemeModel')` in parentheses, when creating an instance. Otherwise you code will be interpreted as:

```
var colourModel = (new jedi.module('AddColourSchemeModel'))({
    // json object containing model values
});
```

So the right way should be:

```
var colourModel = new (jedi.module('AddColourSchemeModel'))({
    // json object containing model values
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all because of how javascript does the binding for 'this', the context when executing a all. It causes initial confusion for people from other different background. [Getting Out of Binding Situations in JavaScript](http://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations) provided excellent explanation on what you are seeing. There are various techniques to address this :-)

Here are a few articles that may help,

- [Getting Out of Binding Situations in JavaScript](http://alistapart.com/article/getoutbindingsituations)
- [Understanding Bind and bindAll in Backbone.js](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2011/08/18/understanding-bind-and-bindall-in-backbone.html)
- [Is var self = this; a bad pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371333/is-var-self-this-a-bad-pattern)
- [what-is-the-difference-between-this-self-window-and-window-self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218292/what-is-the-difference-between-this-self-window-and-window-self)

Hope this help.