# Google OAuth2 + Backbone + Require.js = Problems with "this" binding

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, google-api, oauth-2.0, requirejs

*Google OAuth2 code is based on 
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/authentication*

`LoginView` has a few functions, each function calls another function.

By the time it gets to `checkAuth` function, the `this.handleAuthResult` returns *undefined* because `checkAuth` was called inside the *setTimeout* by `handleClientLoad`.

How to deal with `this` context problem? And can I do the same for my variables - `scope`, `clientId`, `apiKey` instead of making them global?

```
define(['underscore','jquery','backbone','text!templates/login.html','async!https://apis.google.com/js/client.js!onload'], function(_, $, Backbone, loginTpl) {
  var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template(loginTpl),

    initialize: function() {
      clientId = '';
      apiKey = '';
      scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me';

      this.handleClientLoad();
    },

    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template());
      return this;
    },

    handleClientLoad: function() {
      gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
      window.setTimeout(this.checkAuth, 1);
    },

    checkAuth: function() {
      gapi.auth.authorize({ client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true }, this.handleAuthResult);
    },

    handleAuthResult: function(authResult) {
      var authorizeButton = this.$el.find('#authorize-button');

      if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        console.log('Authorized!');
        this.makeApiCall();
      } else {
        authorizeButton.onclick = this.handleAuthClick;
      }
    },

    handleAuthClick: function(event) {
      gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: false}, this.handleAuthResult);
      return false;
    },

    makeApiCall: function() {
      gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function() {
        var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
          'userId': 'me'
        });
        request.execute(function(resp) {
          var authorizeButton = this.$el.find('#authorize-button');
          localStorage.isAuthenticated = true;
          Backbone.history.navigate('', true);
        });
      });
    }
  });

  return LoginView;
});
```

Comment: This question may be apart from your question. How did you solve authentication and security with this library? Does it returns a token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setTimeout in handleClientLoad is the issue:

```
window.setTimeout(this.checkAuth, 1);
```

When 'window.setTimeout' is executed after 1ms and it is no longer executed in LoginView  scope.

You can use ['_.bind'](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) to bind the execution to this.

```
window.setTimeout(_.bind(this.checkAuth, this), 1);
```

You can also read ['this'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908566/this-being-scoped-to-window-object-when-creating-js-object-where-function-is-s/17909682#17909682) posting.

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks this partially helps, but how do I deal with `this.$el` in `var authorizeButton = this.$el.find('#authorize-button');`? **UPDATE**: Solved using `_.bindAll(this, 'handleAuthResult', 'makeApiCall');`.